# How to mute only incoming calls ring and not mute the sms messages

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

how to mute only incoming calls ring and not sms messages and oppesite-mute only sms messages

i tried to use audioManager.setStreamVolume() like

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
switch (mode){
               case CALLS:
                   audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE,0);
                   break;
               case MSGS:
                   audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE,0);
                   break;
               case CALLS_AND_MSGS:
                   audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE,0);
                   audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE,0);
                   break;

           }
```

in all cases both incoming calls and sms messages were mute

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below lines of code

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```